# Convert code with GCD to async/await in Swift?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, completion, swift-concurrency

Approximate example of code I need to achieve using GCD:

```swift
func performTask(completion: (() -> ())?) {
    doSomeAsyncTask { [weak self] isSuccess in
        if isSuccess {
            self?.handleResult(completion: completion)
        } else {
            completion?()
            self?.handleResult(completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

func handleResult(completion: (() -> ())?) {
     …
}

func doSomeAsyncTask(completion: ((Bool) -> ())?) {
    //example of async task which can be successful or not
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion?(Bool.random())
    }
}
```

I want to rewrite it with `async/await` but I don't know how to implement `performTask`. Other methods:

```swift
func handleResult() async {
    …
}

func doSomeAsyncTask() async -> Bool {
    await withCheckedContinuation { checkedContinuation in
        Task {
            checkedContinuation.resume(returning: Bool.random())
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please explain how to implement `performTask`? I can't understand how to deal with situation when sometimes method should call completion and sometimes not.

Comment: Watch “Meet async/await” Apple goes through the whole process of converting. Also that floating Task isn’t necessary and it is usually a cause for a leak.

Comment: An unrelated observation: It is curious that `doSomeAsyncTask` performs some work, but does not return any result (other than the Boolean) and that `handleResult` is not supplied the result to be handled. I assume that the actual result is stored in some property. It is generally preferable for `doSomeAsyncTask` to actually return the results directly (and either throw an error or return `nil` if it failed) and then to supply that value as a parameter to `handleResult`, as needed. There’s not enough here to elaborate (and is beyond the scope of the question), but just a FYI.

Comment: @Rob in my particular case `doSomeAsyncTask` loads an ad, `handleResult` reloads the ad with some checks and time intervals, `completion` usually shows this ad. This logic inside means "load an ad. If it is loaded then show it and continue flow after ad closing. If there is an error then continue flow but try to preload ad (maybe it will be ready next time).

Comment: If that’s the business problem, I’d be inclined to reach for very different approach, namely an asynchronous sequence, e.g., an [`AsyncTimerSequence`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Timer.md) that rotates to the next ad at some interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your completion-handler rendition, if `doSomeAsyncTask` returns `false`, it is immediately calling the closure and then calling `handleResult` with `nil` for the completion handler. This is a very curious pattern. The only thing I can guess is that the intent is to call the completion handler immediately if `doSomeAsyncTask` failed, but still call `handleResult` regardless, but if successful, not to return until  `handleResult` is done.

If that is your intent, the Swift concurrency rendition might be:

```swift
@discardableResult
func performTask() async -> Bool {
    let isSuccess = await doSomeAsyncTask()
    if isSuccess {
        await handleResult()
    } else {
        Task { await handleResult() }
    }
    return isSuccess
}
```

Note, I am returning the success or failure of `doSomeAsyncTask` because, as a matter of best practice, you always want the caller to have the ability to know whether it succeeded or not (even if you do not currently care). So, I made it a `@discardableResult` in case the caller does not currently care whether it succeeded or failed.

The other pattern would be to throw an error if unsuccessful (and the caller can `try?` if it does not care about the success or failure at this point).

```swift
enum ProcessError: Error {
    case failed
}

func performTask() async throws {
    if await doSomeAsyncTask() {
        await handleResult()
    } else {
        Task { await handleResult() }
        throw ProcessError.failed
    }
}
```

Having shown a literal translation of the code you provided, I might suggest a simpler pattern:

```swift
@discardableResult
func performTask() async -> Bool {
    let isSuccess = await doSomeAsyncTask()
    await handleResult()
    return isSuccess
}
```

In the first two alternatives, above, I use unstructured concurrency to handle the scenario where `doSomeAsyncTask` returned `false`, and allow the function to return a result immediately, and then perform `handleResult` asynchronously later. This (like the completion handler rendition) begs the question of how to handle cancelation. And the question is whether `handleResult` is slow enough to justify that pattern, or whether it was a case of premature optimization. It seems exceedingly strange that one would want to await `handleResult` in the success path and not in the failure path. This third and final example simplifies this logic. We do not know enough about the rationale for the original completion-handler rendition to answer that question at this point.